# Linked List Implementation is crashing

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to implement Linked List in C++, when I use the new operator to create the Linked List object (e.g. LinkedList *Head = new LinkedList; etc.) the linked list works fine. But if I use normal pointer object declaration (e.g. LinkedList *Head, *node1, *node2, *node3, *node4;) the program crashes. Could any one of you please explain the reason for this crash?

Below is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct LinkedList {
    int data;
    struct LinkedList* next;
    //Constructor


    // Traversing the Linked List
    void traverseList(struct LinkedList* Head) {
        cout << "The Linked List Elements are: " << endl;
        while (Head != NULL) {
            cout << Head->data << endl;
            Head = Head->next;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    // LinkedList *Head = new LinkedList;
    // LinkedList *node1 = new LinkedList;
    // LinkedList *node2 = new LinkedList;
    // LinkedList *node3 = new LinkedList;
    // LinkedList *node4 = new LinkedList;

    LinkedList *Head, *node1, *node2, *node3, *node4;

    Head->data = 10;
    Head->next = node1;
    node1->data = 20;
    node1->next = node2;
    node2->data = 30;
    node2->next = node3;
    node3->data = 40;
    node3->next = node4;
    node4->data = 50;
    node4->next = NULL;

    Head->traverseList(Head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `Head->data = 10;` what do you think `Head` is pointing to?

Comment: C++ does not work this way. Merely declaring a pointer does not make it automatically point to a valid object. That's why it must be initialized to point to a valid object, either via `new` or by other means. And if you use a pointer that's not pointing to a valid object, you will get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LinkedList *Head, *node1, *node2, *node3, *node4;
```

Merely declaring a pointer in C++ does not mean it points to anything. You need to initialize these so they point to a valid address in memory. Typically this would either be with `new` or by statically allocating them, and then taking the address of those when you need to pass them to a function that expects a pointer.

As a style note, when you see something like:

```
Head->traverseList(Head);
```

There is no need for `transverseList` to be a member function of `LinkedList`. It works better as a standalone function.